# Any help with this algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to make an algorithm in LaTeX. For example, I use this template and I want help for this step

First loop **mik=aik/akk;**

And second loop **aij=aij- mikakj;**

And finally finish with this final loop

**bi=bi=mikbk**;

How to write this in LaTeX code?

```
\section{The algorithm which solves the method Gaussian elimination}
\For{$k$=1$:$1$n-1$}{
    \For{$i=k+1:1:n$}\;
       {write the first loop here}{
      \For{}
      {write the second loop here}
        instructions1\; finish here
        instructions2\;
      {final loop there}
    }{
        instructions3\;
    }
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
```

Sorry for this wrong please help to solve this.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. (See also [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). Could you please also try to further clarify your question by adding a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: Ok  i add the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might serve as a place to start from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Test algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \For{contition}{
        \For{some text here}{
            some text\\
            \For{other stuff}{
                whatever comes here
            }
         some more text
         }
    }

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Test algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\For{$k=1:1:n-1$}{
    \For{$i=k+1:1:n$}{
          $m_{i}{k}=a_{i}{k}/a_{k}{k}$\\
        \For{other stuff}{
            $a_{i}{j}=a_{i}{j}-m_{i}{k}a_{k}{j};$\\
        }
        $b_{i}=b_{i}-m_{i}{k}b_{k};$
    }
}\end{algorithm}
```

is correct